# Is there something wrong with my code?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, debugging, facebox

I don't think there is but this wont load inside facebox:

```
 $("#email").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($("#tinput").val() == "") {
        $('#error').append('You need to select a template.<br />');
    } else if ($("#tsubject").val() == ""){
        $('#error').append('Subject cannot be blank.<br />');
    } else if ($("#tmessage").val() == "") {
        $('#error').append('Message cannot be blank.<br />');
    } else {
        $('#ecanvas').html('<center><img src="/templates/v2/images/loading.gif" /></center>');
        var formdata = $(this).serialize();
        $.post("/wizard/email-add", formdata, function (data) {
            $('#ecanvas').html(data);
        });
    return false;
})
```

This works without any problems:

```
$("#email").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
        $('#ecanvas').html('<center><img src="/templates/v2/images/loading.gif" /></center>');
        var formdata = $(this).serialize();
        $.post("/wizard/email-add", formdata, function (data) {
            $('#ecanvas').html(data);
        });
    return false;
})
```

I should mention #ecanvas, #error, #tinput, #tsubject and #tmessage all exist.

Comment: What does the JavaScript error console say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You failed to close the opening brace of the `else`

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer if it solves the problem?

Comment: I will in about 7 minutes (it won't let me before that).